# Expectation of the logarithm of multivariate Gaussian

Tags: linear-algebra, statistics, probability-distributions, normal-distribution, expected-value

Given $Q(\mathbf{B}) = \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{M},\mathbf{C}_1 \otimes \mathbf{C}_2)$ where $\mathbf{M} = \mathbf{m}_1 \otimes \mathbf{m}_2$, $\mathbf{B} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times k}$, $\mathbf{m}_1 \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $\mathbf{m}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^k$, $\mathbf{C}_1 \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\mathbf{C}_2 \in \mathbb{R}^{k \times k}$ and $\otimes$ denotes outer product. How can I find $E_Q[\ln \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{B} \mid \mathbf{o}_1 \otimes \mathbf{o}_2,\mathbf{D}_1 \otimes \mathbf{D}_2)]$ where $E$ is the expectation and $\mathcal{N}$ denotes normal distribution?

Edit 1: In $E_Q[\ln \mathcal{N}(\mathbf{B} \mid \mathbf{o}_1 \otimes \mathbf{o}_2,\mathbf{D}_1 \otimes \mathbf{D}_2)]$, '$\mid$' denotes conditioned

Comment: are you asking about this? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Differential_entropy

Comment: @MikeHawk It is not differential entropy, I want to find the expected value of ln of $\mathbf{B}$

Comment: the expected value with respect to what distribution?

Comment: @MikeHawk Just edited the question